# Should (or can) master and slave DNS servers have different RRSIG entries?

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, bind

I've just configured DNSSEC on my master DNS server and in testing with dig from each server to the other, I found that while each server had RRSIG entries they were different.

Is this expected behaviour? I see that each server has different times in the signature, so is that causing it? Is this even an issue?

master result:

```
example.com.           600 IN RRSIG NS 5 2 600 (
                                20181225201200 20181125193702 47985 example.com.
                                PNY/8BLZrBZ6Ax27MsblQg/QGPyIrS/uK/xAJY9DXw+s
                                nexXcvRXbEG+3E4yotVtay/ACN4+qMto4Ny87yyM7XFI
                                t0cBHnRx6n1DqU0jX0ARNWWDjaNRW/PlYrTKeqyXesVj
                                Cew44FJDXSd+65PxFlvQRDw6ZIdSbDYdXF1OYMw= )
```

slave result:

```
example.com.           600 IN RRSIG NS 5 2 600 (
                                20181225193928 20181125191401 47985 example.com.
                                b034jrblNOi/Rmm7o34pRMLwH2Qa4dPuJ7ssTGWam/7z
                                b8JTaCtgKwrglzBXzcGaUfcxfCTNeBV0o6HXDvQ7kmx4
                                pZVt8Igvsw/ansIJOsvG+k+nS+ZHTACsgFaOgOegTnNb
                                +SMspj5n54s/mdMhAMreMKYXBPyVEfN0PFVv574= )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected: it is expected that if anything changes in the record, like begin/end dates then the signature itself will change as it is computed over it. It may or may not be expected to see different RRSIG reports at different nameservers of a zone, but this depends a lot on the setup and here it is not described in enough details.

But it happens, see the following.

Same key (key tag `34505`) but each one of the 5 authoritative nameservers provide a different RRSIG (if you compare the sleep for 2 seconds with the signature inception timestamp you can see they are computed on-line at the time of query):

```
$ for ns in `dig NS cloudflare.com. +short` ; do echo -n $ns " " ; dig @$ns cloudflare.com. A +dnssec +short|grep ' 34505 '; sleep 2s; done
ns4.cloudflare.com.  A 13 2 600 20190412164722 20190410144722 34505 cloudflare.com. i7WphUbWNj+0sfA0Mp3gLueKvgDvTDF+p4HuD/x+Weu1Cuglp7Cmx/v/ b0icIaYNsUKzm6OCgDnGQNH27SD8lg==
ns5.cloudflare.com.  A 13 2 600 20190412164724 20190410144724 34505 cloudflare.com. L9/aRuVFtDunNqowLBgYZzahiWhTw7Y82LeEdseBL0ZgJlQSZj8YjB36 Dj89ozZ4KK6zRxPbFmM5VRwwV/rI3Q==
ns7.cloudflare.com.  A 13 2 600 20190412164726 20190410144726 34505 cloudflare.com. khYsYMwEwH/2obxbibonU0gYveHknrtU+pZ6CFr7sLhV2Xv7/DaTKwM7 ABI2mxApVKlEhEz3rQG6XKg/6MPKFg==
ns6.cloudflare.com.  A 13 2 600 20190412164728 20190410144728 34505 cloudflare.com. gJZXNyYpTe7WqjJwaA08M/2ysFkoHze5GEV/XpoWU/y6pOLmt4DhzL4I e/PuEvWQ6agBvtdqzGzSb10p6DQx1A==
ns3.cloudflare.com.  A 13 2 600 20190412164730 20190410144730 34505 cloudflare.com. N0DwRjQKkagAoWn4WuFekvKhPL/juxzGrrn/lOEOpX7Sqmmt+ibaZJf/ YTsSFPtuCgI2hdMBvr/+b9B6rjv4Bg==
```

The `RRSIG` record's signature is computed over everything you see (except the signature itself of course), including hence the owner (that is the domain name on the left) as well as the record types (`NS` here), algorithm (`5` which is "Elliptic Curve [ECC]"), number of label (`2` because `example.com` has 2 labels), original TTL (`600`), signature expiration (`20181225193928`) and signature inception (`20181125191401`), keytag (`47985`) and signer's name (`example.com`). Plus the data in the record being signed (that is the whole content of `example.com. NS` resource record set)

See [RFC 4034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4034) that defines the RRSIG record.

Section 3.1 shows:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|        Type Covered           |  Algorithm    |     Labels    |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                         Original TTL                          |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                      Signature Expiration                     |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                      Signature Inception                      |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|            Key Tag            |                               /
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+         Signer's Name         /
/                                                               /
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
/                                                               /
/                            Signature                          /
/                                                               /
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

and 3.1.8 says:

> The Signature field contains the cryptographic signature that covers
> the RRSIG RDATA (excluding the Signature field) and the RRset
> specified by the RRSIG owner name, RRSIG class, and RRSIG Type
> Covered field.  The format of this field depends on the algorithm in
> use, and these formats are described in separate companion documents.

Comment: It can certainly be acceptable but I don't know about "expected" (other than transitionally). I suppose it depends on the setup, but OP says they use BIND and nothing about doing anything special, so I would expect a very conventional setup. What I would expect from a conventional setup would be that all records (signatures included) are in sync other than transitionally right after changes have been made and the master has new data that slaves have yet to pick up.

Comment: It is expected for on-line signing for example (signatures generated on the fly and cached). Even with off-line signing with 2 separate bind I do not see why their signature schedules should be in sync. But you are right that it depends a lot on the setup, which we do not know about a lot.

Comment: Use of BIND + referring to master and slave sets some expectations. But I agree that it's not completely confirmed what the setup is.

Comment: I still prefer for people to remember that having separate RRSIG like that is not a problem, and as soon as anything is different in the record then the signature is different. So that they are not surprised by it. It may not be the most usual case, but better not to give the false impression of some invariants.

Comment: I slightly reworded by "expected" nevertheless to separate the two points.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I added an example that shows it is not just transitionnally, it happens in the wild, depending on setup of course... The OP just used tag "bind" without explicitely mentioning it in question, nor its version or configuration, which are indeed important points here.

Comment: Indeed, it's certainly possible, depending on where and when the actual signing occurs the way you have things set up. I would still be surprised if OP's setup is such that this is expected for their case, though.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a plain BIND master/slave setup (my take on the question is that this is likely the case), the typical way of doing DNSSEC is signing the master zone and just transferring (`AXFR`/`IXFR`) the already signed zone (the zone transfer would include all records, also the signatures) from there.

If that is the type of setup that the question is about, you would only expect to see differing `RRSIG` records on the different nameservers briefly after changes have been made to the master zone (such as new records or just refreshed signatures), before the updated zone has been transferred by the other nameservers.
If the differing `RRSIG` records persist, there may be something wrong with how zone transfers are set up between the servers (lack of notify?), which would of course not only delay the sync of `RRSIG` records but all changes to the zone. (You may want to compare `SOA.SERIAL` values, like with `dig +nssearch example.com`.)

As has already been detailed by Patrick Mevzek, there are also fundamentally different approaches to zone signing, such as generating signatures on the fly directly on the nameserver answering the query, in which case different signatures from different servers may be the norm rather than just happening in the transitional "out of sync" condition described above.